# get @NITEmisor: value from XML File c#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to get the VALUE @NITEmisor:11984643 how can i Loop using c# thanks for your help.

my first idea is:

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"C:\XML\1A4F032D-F647-4B1B-BD40-9C816037F320.xml");

```
        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/dte:gtdocumento/dte:sat/dte:dte/dte:datosemision/dte:emisor/var[@name='NITEmisor']");
        foreach (XmlNode no in nodeList)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J9kG.png)

Comment: i found the solution for now: 

            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\XML\1A4F032D-F647-4B1B-BD40-9C816037F320.xml");
            string rfc = doc1.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Emisor").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("NITEmisor")).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: read the parent node => string Total = Convert.ToDecimal(doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Total").First().Value).ToString("N2");